# IE7 position fixed issue which Doctype doesn't fix

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Just finishing up a site and having an issue with position: fixed on IE7. I've Googled it and tried different Doctypes but the fixed area is still moving out of position on IE7.

I've not got IE7 but a client staffer has it and I can see the issue using an online IE renderer/tester.

I've removed the .htaccess from the test site so you can see the site/code.

http://drinkzing.com/test

Any advise or help would be appreciated.

Comment: /offtopic: You might me interested in downloading IE Tester http://www.my-debugbar.com/ietester/install-ietester-v0.4.10.exe to test the different versions of IE. The program crashes some times but it's worth it I think if you want to support IE. And no I'm not a shareholder :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<div>` and an `<ul>` element which both have `id="logo-nav"`. They've both set `position:fixed` and some other properties. I think this is the main problem. Remove the duplicate ID, set `position:fixed` only for the `<div>` element and then we can investigate the issue (or the problem should disappear at best).

If you have newer version of Internet Explorer, you may emulate IE7 by clicking the Compatibility View button or choosing IE7 document mode in Developer Tools.

edit: I noticed that you haven't set any `left` property for `#logo-nav`. I don't know why IE7 computes the default position other way than all other browsers, but simply adding `#logo-nav { left: 225px }` works for me.

Comment: compatibility mode is fine, but bear in mind that it isn't a 100% accurate copy of a real version of IE7. For an accurate rendering of what the page looks like in IE7, it is better to use IETester (as recommended in a comment above)

Comment: I've renamed the ul and changed a bit of css to get rid of the position relative. The position absolute is there 'hack' the text links off to the side. However none of this seems to have fixed the IE7 issue sadly.

I'm working on a Mac at the moment so am using remote testing for IE (not ideal I know).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it again duri. I tried adding a left property but it causes the logo-nav div to ignore the auto margins in other browsers (it ignores the fact that it's in a containing div). I guess I could make an IE7 only style sheet using this technique if it comes to it but I'll keep trying to solve it some other way for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
* html idorclasshere {
position: absolute;
}
```

Note: replace "idorclasshere" with your, well, ID or Class of the non-responding div (don't worry, due to the asterisk, other browsers aside from IE won't see it, add it in conjunction to your "position:fixed" style).

Comment: Sorry Andres, can you clarify this a bit for me? should this be in the same CSS rule (#logo-nav) or a separate rule? (* html logo-nav)? Is the html bit needed and does my id need it's '#' in front?

Comment: you can just stick it anywhere you like in your main stylesheet, as a separate rule (i.e. "* html #logo-nav { position: absolute }" ) ..the reason for this is that IE treats position:fixed horribly and you need to hack at it to make it behave. Here is a website with a working example; http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/